# WinApi, disabling all controls in a rect area

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Is there an api to disable all controls in a rect area?
I am trying to write something like that:

GetClientRect(hWnd, rect);
DisableControls(rect);

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Given the code you posted, are you trying to disable all children of a window? In that case, simply disable the parent. It will disable all child controls along with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetClientRect` gets the client area (left and top are always 0), you need to use `GetWindowRect` to figure out where a child window is.

All child controls are in the client area and you can just disable the parent window and all children will also stop accepting input.

It does seem a little contrived to disable based on a rectangle instead of a list of known controls but I suppose it might be useful in some cases.

```
static BOOL CALLBACK DisableChildrenInRectProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM Param)
{
    RECT *pParentRect = (RECT*) Param, r, ir;
    if (GetWindowRect(hWnd, &r) && IntersectRect(&ir, &r, pParentRect))
    {
        EnableWindow(hWnd, FALSE);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

HWND hWnd = ...
RECT r;
GetWindowRect(hWnd, &r);
r.bottom = r.top + (r.bottom - r.top) / 2; // In this example, only disable controls in the top half.
EnumChildWindows(hWnd, DisableChildrenInRectProc, (LPARAM) &r);
```

Comment: If you disable the parent window, you can no longer move the window around or even close it. Also, some controls give visual clues if you disable them individually, which does not happen if you only disable the parent window. For instance, the edit control will draw a grey background when disabled individually. When only the parent window is disabled, it just draws the normal white background.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is one. Use EnumChildWindows, GetWindowRect and some coordinate mapping via ScreenToClient. For overlap testing you could use IntersectRect.